# node-gyp failing: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install, node-gyp

#### npm install fails

I've got a node (vue3) project that i'm trying to install packages for. The install process fails halfway through, specifically the package `node-gyp` is causing the problem. The program has following dependencies:

##### dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.2",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.11.1",
    "@sentry/integrations": "^5.11.1",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-vue": "^3.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "browser-image-resizer": "^2.1.0",
    "bulma": "^0.8.0",
    "bulma-badge": "^3.0.1",
    "bulma-checkradio": "^1.1.1",
    "bulma-pageloader": "^0.3.0",
    "bulma-slider": "^2.0.0",
    "bulma-switch": "^2.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartjs-plugin-colorschemes": "^0.4.0",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^0.7.0",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "idle-vue": "^2.0.5",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.8",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "portal-vue": "^2.1.7",
    "prunecluster": "^2.1.0",
    "sha1": "^1.1.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-analytics": "^5.22.1",
    "vue-bulma-accordion": "^0.3.5",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.4.2",
    "vue-cookie": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-grid-layout": "^2.3.6",
    "vue-json-excel": "^0.2.98",
    "vue-progressbar": "^0.7.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.5",
    "vue-select": "^3.20.0",
    "vue-slider-component": "^3.1.0",
    "vue-socket.io-extended": "^4.0.1",
    "vue-stash": "^2.0.1-beta",
    "vue-tables-2": "1.5.0",
    "vue-tippy": "^4.3.0",
    "vue-tweet-embed": "^2.4.0",
    "vue2-datepicker": "^2.13.2",
    "vue2-leaflet": "^2.4.2",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.20.0",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.5"
  },
```

##### devDependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.5.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.31",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.1.2",
    "exports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "fibers": "^4.0.2",
    "filemanager-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.5",
    "google-fonts-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.4",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.2.0",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.0",
    "postcss-url": "^8.0.0",
    "node-sass": "~6.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-version": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-material-design-icons": "4.4.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-version-file": "^0.1.6"
  }
```

###### nodeVersion: v14.18.1

###### npmVersion: v6.14.15

##### Error logs

```
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2022
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS unknown version "undefined" found at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional"
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.2094) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.17763.0
gyp ERR! find VS - msvs_version does not match this version
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.33027.88) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.17763.0
gyp ERR! find VS - msvs_version does not match this version
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
gyp ERR! find VS - "2017"
gyp ERR! find VS - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - "2017"
gyp ERR! find VS - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\mughamun\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.18.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\mughamun\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.18.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\mughamun\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.18.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\mughamun\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.18.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\mughamun\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.18.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\mughamun\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.18.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\mughamun\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.18.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:390:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1058:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\mughamun\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v14.18.1\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Dev\OnlineSystemsApp\node_modules\fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v14.18.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-gyp exited with code: 1
```

`node-gyp` is unable to find a valid visual studio installation. I've **VS 2022 Prof** and **VS 2017 Community** installed, node-gyp is able to detect **VS 2017** but says invalid msvs_version was set.  I manually set the msvs_version to 2017 using `npm config set msvs_version 2017` but that didn't work, same for VS 2022.

**Some other things i've tried.**

- Tried global install of node-gyp
- Tried building it from source
- Used different node versions
- Tried installing windows-build-tools globally
- Tried to run install script on clean install of windows on multiple computers, on some it worked

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest version of node-gyp

npm i node-gyp@latest

then run npm i

Your errors are solved.

Comment: Tried that already, doesn't help. Same error

Comment: Did you install node-gyp successfully, as long as it won't installed successfully it won't work, strange I got solved this error twice with the same solution.

Comment: Yes it was installed successfuly.